# Unable to embed Pdfium - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, pdfium

After successfully building Pdfium as per [Google's docs](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/), I created a new C++ console app with VS2022 and tried to embed `.lib` resulting from Pdfium build but, it results in several unresolved symbols which, I guess, should be included in standard C++. As an example, here is two of the unresolved symbols:

```
fx_string.obj: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::Cr::__libcpp_verbose_abort(char const *,...)"
fpdf_parser_utility.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::Cr::basic_ostream<char,struct std::Cr::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::Cr::basic_ostream<char,struct std::Cr::char_traits<char> >::write(char const *,__int64)"
```

**Steps taken**:

- build Pdfium following [docs steps](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/) using below `args.gn`:

  ```
  use_goma = false
  is_debug = false
  pdf_use_skia = false
  pdf_enable_xfa = false
  pdf_enable_v8 = false
  pdf_is_standalone = false
  is_component_build = false
  pdf_is_complete_lib = true
  ```
- Created a simple C++ console app with following content (copied from [Getting started](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/refs/heads/main/docs/getting-started.md)):

  ```cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include "../PDFium/public/fpdfview.h"

  int main()
  {
       std::cout << "PDFium test!\n";

       FPDF_LIBRARY_CONFIG config{};
       config.version = 2;
       config.m_pUserFontPaths = NULL;
       config.m_pIsolate = NULL;
       config.m_v8EmbedderSlot = 0;

       FPDF_InitLibraryWithConfig(&config);

       FPDF_DestroyLibrary();

       return 0;
  }
  ```
- Copied Pdfium's public folder and resulting `.lib` file into a separate folder of the project, added necessary fields for linker and set C++ language spec to `stdc++20`; below, the corresponding tags in `.vcxproj`

  ```xml
  <!-- other tags -->
  <ClCompile>
       <!-- other tags -->
       <LanguageStandard>stdcpp20</LanguageStandard>
       <LanguageStandard_C>stdc11</LanguageStandard_C>
  </ClCompile>
  <!-- other tags -->
  <Link>
       <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
       <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
       <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(SolutionDir)PDFium\x64</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
       <AdditionalDependencies>PDFium.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
  </Link>
  ```

**(Unsuccessful) Tests did**

- Tried to compile PDFium with and without `pdf_is_complete_lib = true`, and thus, linking also single `.obj`s, and `v8` and `xfa` support
- Tried to compile with Microsoft's `clang-cl` instead of `MSBuild` (the one provided by Visual Studio's Native Development pack)
- Tried to compile with depot tools's `clang-cl` (currently, version `16.0.0`)
- Tried several options found here and there on SO and on internet

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know what your problem is but for what it is worth, I had so many problems building pdfium on Windows years ago that I just stopped trying to follow Google's instructions and put together my own Visual Studio solution.
https://github.com/jwezorek/vs_pdfium
it is kind of out of date now though. Ill probably pull new code and getting it up to date in 2023 at some point.

Comment: @jwezorek I took a look at your repo before writing this question, and also tried to take inspiration from what you did, but unsuccessfully. I will try again getting rid of `ninja` and letting VS do the magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of failures and (vain) research, I finally found the solution, posted here for future reference.

#### TL;DR;

Depending on flags set in `args.gn`, Pdfium will need **at least** the following to successfully build and start the [Getting Started](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/refs/heads/main/docs/getting-started.md) example:

- if `is_component_build = false` and, thus `pdf_is_complete_lib = true`, `.obj` files built from `libc++`  and `winmm.lib`
- if `is_component_build = true` and, thus `pdf_is_complete_lib = false`, all `.dll` resulting from compilation, i.e.:

  - `absl.dll`
  - `icuuc.dll`
  - `libc++.dll`
  - `partition_alloc.dll`
  - `pdfium.dll`
  - `zlib.dll`

Read also the important note below which tries to explain the difference between the two flags.

#### Long description

As per [docs](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/#selecting-build-configuration), once `.ninja` files has been generated as result of `gn args <out_dir>`, it can be seen which `.obj`, `.lib` and `.dll` files are needed to build `pdfium_unitests.exe`. Comparing those with the ones used to generate `pdfium.lib` (or `pdfium.dll` depending on flags, see below), it can be spotted the required libraries.

With `is_component_build = false` and `pdf_is_complete_lib = true`:

- start default compilation with `ninja -C <out_dir>`; this also builds libc++;
- generate `pdfium.lib` via `ninja -C <out_dir> pdfium` (will only execute a link step)
- (*optionally*) generate a `libc++.lib` using depot tool's lld-link which will contain all `.obj` files from compilation of libc++:

  ```
  "C:\path\to\pdfium\third_party\llvm-build\Release+Asserts\bin\lld-link.exe" /lib /OUT:libc++.lib /nologo /WX /ignore:4221 <space-separated list of .obj files in C:\out_dir\obj\buildtools\third_party\libc++\libc++>
  ```
- link `pdfium.lib`, all libc++'s `.obj` files in `C:\out_dir\obj\buildtools\third_party\libc++\libc++` (or, `libc++.lib` from previous step), `winmm.lib` in your project; e.g.:

  ```xml
  <Link>
      <!-- other options -->
      <AdditionalDependencies>pdfium.lib;libc++.lib;winmm.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
  </Link>
  ```

With `is_component_build = true` and `pdf_is_complete_lib = false`:

- start compilation with `ninja -C <out_dir> pdfium`; will compile all the necessary `.dll`s along with `.pdb` and `.lib` files and put them in `out_dir`
- link `pdfium.lib` in your project and copy emitted `.dll`s in output directory; assuming emitted files are in `C:\pdfium\result`, project's `.vcxproj` will look like this:

  ```xml
  <!-- ... -->
  <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\pdfium\result</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>pdfium.dll.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
  </Link>
  <!-- ... -->
  <PostBuildEvent>
      <Command>cmd /c "robocopy C:\pdfium\result $(OutDir) /xf *.lib &amp; if %errorlevel% geq 8 exit 0 else exit %errorlevel%"</Command>
  </PostBuildEvent>
  <!-- ... -->
  ```

  **Note**: the files you'll need are listed in tl;dr; section.
  **Note 2**: used [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) because is more efficient than `xcopy`. Also, check on exit code is needed because of the [value returned by `robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#exit-return-codes)

#### Important note

`pdf_is_complete_lib` and `is_component_build` will set, respectively, `/MT` and `/MD` flags during compilation.

Although might not seem a problem, MSBuild will complain if the two types are mixed and thus, you'll need either to recompile Pdfium or change the way your code is generated via *Project Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library*.

For more information see [Google docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/component_build.md), Microsoft docs on [flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170) and [linker warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4098?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) and, eventually, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148933/libcmt-conflicts-with-use-of-other-libs-unresolved-external-symbols) which can help in choose the code generation that most suits your needs.

Comment: congratulations.